alguien puede orientarme sobre porque esta funcion no hace su trabajo
Hola hace mucho que no toco este mundo y estoy volviendo a ir colocandome en el sitio , poco a poco y practiacando la cuestion es que estoy en un trabajo , personal para practicar e ir actualizandome , y hay una funcion que me esta dando muchos quebraderos de cabeza... es una funcion para comprimir en zip unas imagenes al actualizarlas desde el backend... la cuestion es que lo que quiero hacer es , pongo un ejemplo... tengo dos imagenes , la imagen 1 y la imagen 2 , si actualizo la imagen 1 quiero que la imagen vieja se me comprima en un zip, si por el contrario actualizo la imagen 2 quiero que sea la imagen 2 la que se comprima en un zip, pero que si actualizo las 2 imagenes , se me compriman las 2 imagenes .. no se si me he explicado bien... subo el codigo...
 <?php
function compressOldImages($modelDir, $headerImage, $mainImage) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zipFile = $modelDir . 'old_images_' . time() . '.zip';
    $zipCreated = false;
    if ($zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        if ($headerImage) {
            $fileInfo = pathinfo($headerImage);
            $oldHeaderImage = $modelDir . $fileInfo['filename'] . " Header." . $fileInfo['extension'];
            if (file_exists($oldHeaderImage)) {
                $zip->addFile($oldHeaderImage, basename($oldHeaderImage));
                $zipCreated = true;
            }
        }
        if ($mainImage) {
            $fileInfo = pathinfo($mainImage);
            $oldMainImage = $modelDir . $fileInfo['filename'] . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
            if (file_exists($oldMainImage)) {
                $zip->addFile($oldMainImage, basename($oldMainImage));
                $zipCreated = true;
            }
        }
        if ($zipCreated) {
            $zip->close();
        } else {
            $zip->close();
            unlink($zipFile); // Eliminar el archivo ZIP si no se agregó ningún archivo
        }
    }
}

 // mas abajo en la parte de código que toca....

 // Preparar imágenes a comprimir
    $headerImage = $img_header['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ? $img_header['name'] : null;
    $mainImage = $img_perfil['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ? $img_perfil['name'] : null;

    // Comprimir imágenes antiguas si hay alguna para comprimir
    if ($headerImage || $mainImage) {
        compressOldImages($modelDir, $headerImage, $mainImage);
    }
?>

espero que alguien pueda ayudarme u orientarme

Hola. La pregunta no se entiende. ¿Por qué en lugar de hablar de imagen 1  e imagen 2 no usas por ejemplo los nombres de las variables que ya están en el código? Dicho eso, ¿cuál es el problema o error? ¿qué resultado esperas y qué resultado obtienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

las variables estan puestas , el resultado que busco es que si actualizo o cambio la imagen 1 , la imagen que sustituyo se comprima en zip, si cambio la 2 que la imagen que sustituyo se me comprima en un zip y si cambio las 2  , las 2 que sustituyo que se me compriman en un mismo zip el problema es que no me comprime ninguna....gracias por contestar..
